# Rank of Matrix and Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $B \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb F)$ has rank $r$, then there exist $v_1...v_r \in \mathbb F^m$ and $w_1...w_r \in \mathbb F^n$ such that $B = \sum_{i=1}^{r}v_i w_i^T.$

I'm not really sure how to begin. I tried writing the columns of $B$ in terms of a basis, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ has the rank $r$, then there exist invertible matrices $V_{m\times m}$ and $W_{n\times n}$ such that
$$B=V\cdot D\cdot W,$$
where $D$ is the $m\times n$-matrix, with $D_{i,i}=e, i\in\{1,...,r\}$ and zero others ([Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)). So, if $V'$ and $W'$ are left-top $r\times r$-submatrices of corresponding matrices, then
$$B= V'\cdot W'.$$ 
From the last equation you can obtain required.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer; could you explain please?

Comment: Whys there exist such $V, W$? Or further steps?